# Will this be global for the whole site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, xml-parsing

I need to load an xml file into memory and have it available for globally for the whole site. Does this code accomplish this?

If so, how is updating this "cached" version accomplished in the future?

```
XPathDocument ConvProductDoc;

    ConvProductDoc = Cache["doc"] as XPathDocument;
    if (ConvProductDoc == null) {
        ConvProductDoc = new XPathDocument(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(@"\data\foo\bar\my.xml"));
        Cache.Insert("doc", ConvProductDoc);
    }
```

Comment: depends on what `Cache` is and how your site is configured.

Comment: OK, please forgive my ignorance, is there a link that can explain what you're suggesting further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the ASP.NET `Cache` object is site wide.  There are a lot of options for managing the `Cache` and setting expiration rules, etc.

To assign/update the value in `Cache`, you simply set it like you would any `Dictionary` or `HashTable` value:

```
Cache["doc"] = newValue;
```

You can read a lot more about the `Cache` object in the MSDN Docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx#aspnet-cachingtechniquesbestpract_topic4

Comment: @SoftwareSpint makes a good point below about sites distributed across multiple servers, however ASP.NET has built-in mechanisms for managing cache across multiple servers.  This article may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942840.aspx

Comment: What about new file detection? I'm sure that's possible right?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly use a `FileSystemWatcher` that would monitor a file, however it would be a separate operation you'd have to make use of - you would monitor the file and then manually update the `Cache` based on changes to the file.  And you'll need to consider where the file is located - on one of the servers, or any of them?  You can read more about `FileSystemWatcher` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Comment: Actually no, the cache object is per pool, if you use two pools to run your site at the same computer then you have 2 diferent cache objects.

Comment: @Aristos, yes I suppose if you're running the same site in two different pools, then yes, they would not share the same Cache, but in that case, they are essentially two different applications, aren't they?  I don't have any experience with this scenario - can you really map one site/url to two application pools?

Comment: @BrianS Yes, if you search for web garden, you see how. In the case of web garden and web farm, only the file system (and/or a common database) can be real the same across apps.

Comment: I'm not using a pool. I don't think it's needed. I just don't want a given server's resources overwhelmed because of HD calls. Thanks guys... I'll read through the links you gave me. You've all been a great help!

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that tip @Aristos.  In that case, you'd probably need to use a StateServer or SQLServer for storing state, even if its on a single server?

Answer (score 1):

If you website is only on one server then yes.

If your website is distributed over more than one server then no.
The cache key and data will only be available on the server in which it has been stored.

If you server is in Amazon EC2 for example, you could use ElastiCache which would ensure the cache is available over a distributed server environment.

Comment: Got it, yes, that makes sense, and, for me, a given. This would be fine. So the short answer is "yes, on that server only"? I am load balanced between six servers, I think (the page gets 5k hits a day).

Comment: @Jimmmy, so `Cache` is a http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx

Comment: The correct is "on one pool" not on one server, because if you have web garden (more pools runs) then every pool have their cache.